# Why does reloading nginx not enact certain configuration file changes?

Tags: nginx, reload, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, restart

I was pulling my hair out earlier today...

I kept changing a single line in my site's configuration file and reloading nginx.

The line in particular was:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=2:2:2 keys_zone=custom_cache:10m inactive=60m;
```

That makes the cache 3 levels deep of 2 char directories per level.

I tried changing that to:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:1 keys_zone=custom_cache:10m inactive=60m;
```

Deleting the entire cache with `rm -rf /var/cache/nginx/` and then reloading nginx and it was still giving me 3 levels deep of 2 char directories per level. (When the expected outcome was 2 levels deep of 1 char directories per level.)

When I restarted nginx, the configuration file was read as expected and I started getting the levels of caching that I wanted.

Why does nginx act that way?

I was under the impression that reloading the service was the best practice since it gracefully shuts down the service instead of forcefully quitting.

Does reloading nginx keep some cache settings in it's own cache or something?

I had a similar experience changing rewrite and return directives on `reload`. No change. But on `restart`, changes enabled.

Comment: The browser also has a cache and needs to be reset between tests to obtain consistent results.

Comment: How would the browser know I restarted instead of reloaded nginx though?